# Is it better to call functions in middle of script or at end of script? Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I have a few python scripts, and each one of them consist of multiple functions. I was wondering if it is better (meaning faster, and cleaner) to run the function right after the function is created, or to create all of the functions, and then run them in order at the end of the script. when I say "run them" I mean calling myfunction() after the function is over, or waiting for the end of the script and calling something like:

```
myFunction()
myFunction2()
myFunction3()
```

I'll add a little more detail. I have 4 scripts, each of them consist of functions that must be used from other scripts. for example I have one script that, grabs a users login information and logs them into a website, cancels their account, and then returns their data from said site. then I have a scrip that will resume their account, but in order to do so I need to use the login function from the previous script. So I was wondering if, since I am using each function in multiple scripts if it was more efficient to call them all at the end using a "**name**==**main**" or to just call them as I create them.

Comment: There's no real "better". You call functions in in a specific order and at a specific place to accomplish your task. This is not a design issue.

Comment: If you run a function right away, why is it function then?

Comment: @Klaus D. because I have multiple scripts that work to accomplish one thing, and I need them to be accessible from other scripts. and to me, it seems like it is faster to run the function right after I make it instead of at the end.

Comment: To each his own, but I think Its better to call them all together at the end where people expect the calls should be. In fact, they should be called within an `if __name__=="__main__:` condition  - see [Top-level script environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__)

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim I was asking because I have multiple scripts that work to accomplish the same goal, so each script has to have functions that I can call them from other scripts. Right now I am running" __name__ == _main" at the end of the file, but it seems like it's faster to run each function right after I create it...

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, that's what i'm doing now, calling them all at the end with a __name__==__main__. I just wanted to know if it was better practice to do that, or to call them directly after they are created.

Comment: If your script is something you call from the command line, you'll have one entry point function and that will be under the `__name__` import guard. If your script is a library which other scripts will call, there won't be any top level invocations in any functions. Just a bunch of definitions. In your specific case, I think it's a script so putting all the invocations in a single function and then calling that under the import guard sounds like the right thing to do.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim - I get what you're saying but one other concern is automatic documentation scanners that expect modules to be loaded without side effects.

Comment: As projects grow, there should be few functions in a top level script. If you found the function useful in one place, it may well be useful in others. Placing them in importable modules is a natural progression.

Comment: @tdelaney If you have an import guard, there won't be any side effects. One of the many reasons I recommend against calling things at the top level and calling multiple things inside the guard.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on your need and programming practices, so none of them is better over other
If you want to keep your code clean, I would suggest that keep all the similar functions in a class then import that class in another class where you can call the function on the object/ class

Example

> File : user.py

```
class Essential(object):
    def init(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
```

> File : main.py (here we will actually run the app/ entry-point for the app)

```
from user import Essential
if __name__=='__main__':
    obj = Essential('John')
    name = obj.getName()
    print(name)
```

This will keep everything bit modular and easy to manage both physically and logically

Comment: I guess this is why we should be careful about opinions - flame wars ensue - but, ..., yuck. A `getter` like `getName` for no reason? Putting things into classes just to hide them one more namespace deep? This would not pass my code review!

Comment: @tdelaney I just presented a simple example and not submitting a pull request to you for review